# magento custom email sending

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I am trying to send a custom mail template. I followed [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/) article. It is working but the emails are all blank. Any Suggestions?

EDIT:
Now after rechecking mail is not blank anymore. But, current problem I am facing is I am sending mail from arabic store and my mail is in arabic language. But the text in the mail received is not in arabic due to some encoding problems. Can anyone tell me how to fix my mail encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using php mail function I used zend mail function with utf-8.

```
    $mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($processedTemplate);
    $mail->setFrom($from_email);
    $mail->addTo($usermail, 'No reply');
    $mail->setSubject('My sUBJECT');
    $mail->send();
```